# use python watchdog without the logging module?

Tags: python, watchdog

The documentation for watchdog only has examples that are coupled to logging.

Is an example available that shows receiving the events in a way to trigger other program actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial by Bruno Rocha exactly meets the need I stated. http://brunorocha.org/python/watching-a-directory-for-file-changes-with-python.html